# Representing a file in MongoDB

Tags: mongodb

I would like to process a CSV or Excel file, convert it into JSON and store it in MongoDB for a particular user. I would then like to do queries that filter depending on the user id, file name, or by attributes in the cells.

The method suggested to me is that each document would represent a row from the CSV/Excel file. I would add the filename and username to every single row.
Here is an example of one `document` (row)

```
{ user_id: 1, file_name: "fileName.csv", name: "Michael", surname: "Smith"},
```

The problem I have with this is that every time a query is executed it will have to go through the whole database and filter out any rows not associated with that user id or filename. If the database contained tens of millions of rows then surely this would be very slow?

The structure I would think is better is this but this I've been told it wouldn't be fast to query. I would have thought it would be quicker as now you just need to find one entry by user id, then the files you want to query, then the rows.

```
{
   "user_id":1,
   "files":[
      {
         "file_name":"fileName.csv",
         "rows":[
            {
               "name":"Michael",
               "surname":"Smith"
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

I'm still rather new to MongoDB so I'm sure it's just a lack of understanding on my part.

What is the best representation of the data?

Comment: How you model the data is really up to you; there is no single "correct" answer. However: just know that your 2nd example (with array) has an "unbounded array" issue - if your CSV is too large, there is a possibility of exceeding maximum document size. You might want to spend time reading up on indexing, since that's how MongoDB deals with filtering out millions of documents efficiently.

Comment: I didn't think of there being a document size limit! The main thing I was thinking about was that if you could get the document for a particular user and then search within it then overall less computation would be needed. Seeing as there is a document size limit then indexing makes a lot more sense.